# Why does count( distinct ) with NULL columns return 0 in Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, count, hive, null, distinct

I have struggled with an issue in Hive SQL and just found out what the issue was:

```
select distinct 'A', NULL;
```

returns 'A', NULL

```
select count(distinct 'A', NULL);
```

returns 0

```
select count(distinct 'A', coalesce(NULL,''));
```

returns 1.

I was using the select line inside of a larger query and filtered on the result (=1). With the outcome being 0, I lost a lot of rows.

How come that a row with NULL column does not contribute to the result of a count(distinct) query?

Comment: The definition of count() is to count values that are not null. If there is a null value it won't be counted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the interface of `count` in hive:

`count(*)` counts all rows

`count(col1)` counts all rows where col1 is not null

`count(distinct col1,col2...)` counts all distinct rows where the specified columns are not null

As a solution to your specific problem, you can try to have a nested query with the logic and use `count(*)` in the outer query:

`select count(*) from (select distinct 'A', NULL) a;`
returns 1

Comment: So all of the colums must be not NULL? That does explain.